# Headless UI Dialog is hiding ALL scrollbars on mobile. Why?

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, headless-ui

Package: @headlessui/react v1.7.14

Chrome and Safari - Desktop and Mobile

The problem is with Headless UI's slide-in Dialog component.

On desktop, everything works beautifully. The scrollbar appears *when I'm scrolling*, otherwise is hidden.

On desktop dev tools (Chrome dev tools --> mobile iOS), everything works beautifully. Again, the scrollbar appears *when I'm scrolling*, otherwise is hidden.

On a *real* mobile device (my iPhone SE), when the dialog is open, there is no scrollbar -- for some reason, it is hidden. I am using a custom scrollbar and need it to appear on the screen in order for things to function properly.
My hunch is that this is related to Headless UI's underlying scroll lock functionality, but I'm really not sure. Any help would be much appreciated!

Here is my implementation:

```
<Transition.Root show={open} as={Fragment}>
        <Dialog
          as="div"
          className="z-30 fixed inset-0 sm:overflow-hidden"
          onClose={handleClose}
        >
          <div className="absolute inset-0 sm:overflow-hidden">
            <Dialog.Overlay className="absolute inset-0" />

            <div className="pointer-events-none fixed transform sm:top-0 right-0 flex h-full sm:pb-0 sm:w-500">
              <Transition.Child
                as={Fragment}
                enter="transform transition ease-in-out duration-500 sm:duration-700"
                enterFrom="translate-x-full"
                enterTo="translate-x-0"
                leave="transform transition ease-in-out duration-500 sm:duration-700"
                leaveFrom="translate-x-0"
                leaveTo="translate-x-full"
              >
                <div className="pointer-events-auto w-screen">
```

Comment: Jonathan Stern I had same issue with IOS devices, I solved it by using an example from their docs https://headlessui.com/react/dialog#scrollable-dialogs.

Comment: It wasn't clear... is your scrolling issue having to do with A) scrolling in the regular page (when modal is closed), or B) scrolling within the modal content (when modal is open) ? If A, check that your modal is actually closed including the modal background. In any case, fyi HeadlessUI's Dialog ultimately renders as a native HTML `dialog` which comes with the benefit of locking scrolling (or any interaction, like tabbing) outside of the dialog. In the past you'd have to manage that yourself.